# React redux returning unknown state objects

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am returning state from a reducer and while mapping it to props the state gets changed containing other unknown objects!

**My code**

Reducer & store:

```
const reducer = async (state = { dataList: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        // Some cases
    }
    console.log(state) // Output: {"dataList": []}
    return state
}

const store = createStore(reducer)
```

*Output of state of reducer: `{"dataList": []}`*

Props collector:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state) // Output: {"_40": 0, "_55": {"dataList": []}, "_65": 1, "_72": null}
    return {
        dataList: state.dataList
    }
}
```

*Output of props: `{"_40": 0, "_55": {"dataList": []}, "_65": 1, "_72": null}`*

**How should I get rid of this extra data coming in?**

*Note:* The code was plumbered from a tested source.

Comment: How are your reducers used with createStore and with combineReducer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the async-await from your reducer function and it will resolve it.

instead of doing this

```
const reducer = async (state = { dataList: [] }, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    // Some cases
}
console.log(state) // Output: {"dataList": []}
return state
```

}

do this

```
const reducer = (state = { dataList: [] }, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    // Some cases
}
console.log(state) // Output: {"dataList": []}
return state
```

}